# Date value output

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong here I am trying to get the current date to be in the input box, however if I change the date I want the new value to be there?

But currently no matter what date I enter it outputs the current date.

```js
function display_array() {
    ////////////Date convert
    var d = new Date();
    var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var dd = d.getDate();
    var yy = d.getFullYear();
    var Dateissue = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy; //(US)
    document.getElementById("DateissueO").innerHTML = "Date of issue:  " + Dateissue;
    
    var Dateissue = document.getElementById("DateissueO").value;
}
    
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('Dateissue').value = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA')
}
```

```html
<INPUT id="button" onclick="display_array();" class="button" type="button" value="Submit">
    Date of Issue: <INPUT name="Dateissue" id="Dateissue" type="date">
<DIV id="DateissueO"></DIV>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your `Date` object with the selected date.

Get the new date from element `Dateissue` and convert it to the compatible date format for `new Date(YYYY/MM/DD)` constructor.

```
document.getElementById('Dateissue').value.replace(/-/g, '/')
```

## Look at this code snippet

```js
function display_array() {
    ////////////Date convert
    var d = new Date(document.getElementById('Dateissue').value.replace(/-/g, '/'));
    var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var dd = d.getDate();
    var yy = d.getFullYear();
    var Dateissue = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy; //(US)
    document.getElementById("DateissueO").innerHTML = "Date of issue:  " + Dateissue;
    
    var Dateissue = document.getElementById("DateissueO").value;
}
    
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('Dateissue').value = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA')
}
```

```html
<INPUT id="button" onclick="display_array();" class="button" type="button" value="Submit">
    Date of Issue: <INPUT name="Dateissue" id="Dateissue" type="date">
<DIV id="DateissueO"></DIV>
```

See? now is using the new selected date from field `Dateissue`.